# How to disable long click on XWalkView (Crosswalk Project) in Android

Tags: android, selection, long-press

It does not work.

- setLongClickable(true);
- setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()..

Answer (score 1):

Set OnLongClickListener and override onLongClick. By returning true, the long click event will be treated as consumed.

```
mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
});
```